# Variable unused in Go

Tags: go

The following code generates the compile error : "err declared and not used". If there is a scope/shadowing issue here, it's due to a principle I don't understand. Can someone explain?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var (
        err error
        dto = make(map[string]interface{})
    )

    dto[`thing`],err = getThings();
    fmt.Println(dto[`thing`]);
}

func getThings() (string,error) {
    return `the thing`,nil
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with "shadowing". You are assigning a value to `err`, but never accessing it.

Comment: Facepalm. The compiler generates the error for the line where it's declared instead of where it's assigned, so I focused there. In the real code, there's a shadowed err var that further masks the error. Thanks....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not because of any shadowing. You have not used `err` variable that is  declared for anything but assigning a value to it .

according to FAQ

> The presence of an unused variable may indicate a bug, while unused
>   imports just slow down compilation. Accumulate enough unused imports
>   in your code tree and things can get very slow. For these reasons, Go
>   allows neither

If you declare a variable it has to be used

In the given program `err` is declared and is being used to assign data to .The value of `err` is not used at all

You may bipass this kind of error by doing a _ assignment

ie,

```
  var _ = err
```

or
  using `err` like

```
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err.Error())
      return
  }
```

The following code would solve it,but i would suggest use the err for checking error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var (
        err error
        dto = make(map[string]interface{})
    )
    _ = err

    dto[`thing`], err = getThings()
    fmt.Println(dto[`thing`])
}

func getThings() (string, error) {
    return `the thing`, nil
}
```

**PS :** You must use variables you declare inside functions, but it's **OK** if you have unused global variables. It's also OK to have unused function arguments.