# How to define a connect to DB function in golang using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

Good morning,
I am new to golang. I am creating following connect to DB function:

```
func ConnectDatabase(db gorm.Dialector, gorm.Config gorm.Option) *gorm.DB{
    
    db, err := gorm.Open(db, gormConfig)
    
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return db
    }
```

It gives me an error on Open: cannot use gorm.Open(db, gormConfig)(value of type *gorm.DB) as gorm.Dialector value in assignment: *gorm.DB does not implement gorm.Dialector

The reason I create the function with two parameteres is because i want to wright the test on it, and need to pass test parameters to it

My test code looks like it:

```
    func TestDbConnect(t *testing.T){
        dbFile, err := os.CreateTemp("", "sample_db"
        if err != nil{
           t.Fatal(err)
         }
        sqlOpen := sqlite.Open(dbFile.Name())
        gormConfig := &gorm.Config{}
        conn, err := sqlOpen, gormConfig
}
```

Would really appreciate an advice on how to define my function correctly and if my test function makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have some improper function signature ,in parameters .I have fixed your code .Now you can use it

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
    
        "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
        "gorm.io/gorm"
    )
    
    func ConnectDatabase(db gorm.Dialector, config *gorm.Config, option gorm.Option) (*gorm.DB,err) {
    
        db1, err := gorm.Open(db, config)
    
        if err != nil {
            return nil,err // return nil and error here
        }
        return db1,nil
    }
    
    func main() {
        sql := sqlite.Open("test.db")
        db := ConnectDatabase(sql, &gorm.Config{}, nil)
        fmt.Println("Hello, World!", db)
    }
```

Points -
1- `Dialector` is an interface of gorm

2- sqlite.Open("test.db") returns `Dialector interface`

Your test would look something like this

```
func TestDbConnect(t *testing.T){
        dbFile, err := os.CreateTemp("", "sample_db"
        if err != nil{
           t.Fatal(err)
         }
         sqlOpen := sqlite.Open(dbFile.Name())
         db,err := ConnectDatabase(sqlOpen, &gorm.Config{}, nil)
         // handle error and test pass case
       
       
       
}
```

Also don't make function local variable name as parameter name,this may cause **variable shadowing** see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708697/variable-shadowing-in-go)  as you are having err variable as new one in this line

```
db, err := gorm.Open(db, gormConfig)
```

so go complier was not giving error.